# Approach to convert an android activity to a phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, android-activity

I have created a JAVA android activity which is completed and can be compiled as APK and installed at the android phone.

I have implemented a phonegap android app and also able to be compiled and installed at the android phone.

Now i want the phonegap android app able to call the JAVA activity, and properly just receive a simple string from that.

**The problem is i want both of them able to build as 1 apk. It means that the JAVA android activity doesn't exist on the mobile phone before the phonegap app is installed**

Is it possible? If yes, what is the regular approach to do so? Should i create a phonegap plugin and the JAVA android activity?

Also is it possible to include the whole JAVA android activity in the phonegap apk? If yes, is there an article describing it?

Comment: you don't need an activity to get a simple string, just develop a phonegap plugin that return that string

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by searching the website.

It is because i am not only new to phonegap and i am also new to android

but it is quite simple after understood the structure of phonegap

the solution:

by running the phonegap tutorial : phonegap create ,

a phonegap solution is created, and running phonegap add android.

the phonegap will auto create the /platforms for the android

under the folder /platforms there should be an android folder

actually this folder can be extracted to eclipse and run without any extra work (if it is modified or some packet is added. you may just make sure the packet is working properly, my experience is eclipse sometime read the packet of phonegap as folder in the /src of android platform).

that it if someone who familiarize with android as there is a working solution for the android platform (i totally have no idea why the phonegap documentation can be that complex for integrate phonegap with eclipse).

---

to communicate Javascript and android activity.

the trick can be totally completed in this solution.

firstly the most important to make these thing work is to ensure the javascript can communicate with the JAVA plugin.

JAVA plugin for android platform is just one of the .java in the /src

and it can be called by this command in the javascript

```
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
            callback(err);
        }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);
```

this is the cordova function to call the JAVA function as plugin in the javascript environment where

callback = function(ex) {alert(ex);}; and [str] is just a string array to pass the value to the plugin if needed.

the most importance is the "Echo" which is the plugin name that required to be registered in the config.xml in /res/xml/config.xml.

and those line should be existed so that cordova will able to reach the Echo class

```
        <feature name="Echo">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Echo" />
        </feature>
        <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Echo" />
```

---

as simple as that the phonegap can communicate with JAVA now and it is under the platform of the eclipse & android. To call an android activity in this environment

you can just

1. add your activity (if you are using some /res related material for example layout and image, you need to ensure you are importing a correct R class, it is very weird that you can use android.R, in my case i need to specify to call .R for example org.com.helloworld.R).
2. modify the androidmanifest.xml to add this activity (just like any other android development)

after these 2 steps, the environment already can find out the android activity

and then you can simply intent the android activity in the phonegap JAVA plugin

you may ask 2 things like most of the people.

Q: what is the main android activity in cordova(or phonegap)

A: firstly import

```
        import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
```

in the JAVA plugin so that you can call the class of cordova, then the main activity of the phonegap can be retrieved by calling

```
        this.cordova.getActivity()
```

Q: how the plugin retrieve the return data if you call startActivityForResult to call the JAVA activity instead of startActivity.

A: Simply, cordova allows you to set the JAVA plugin for the callback activity by

```
    this.cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
```

after doing this, the below class that in the JAVA plugin should be triggered when the intent activity is finished.

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("Phonegap", "onActivityResult called");
        }
```